# How to set collection items for in-clause in jpql?

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, jpa-2.0, jpql

Is there a possiblity in JPA 2.0 to set a collection for in-clause in jpql-query?
(I'm using EclipseLink)

The next example fails:

```
TypedQuery<Person> q = em.createQuery("select p from Person p where p.name in (?1)", Person.class);

List<String> names = Arrays.asList(new String[] { "Bill Gates", "Steve Jobs" });
// THIS FAILS
q.setParameter(1, names);

List<Person> persons = q.getResultList();
for (Person p: persons) {
    System.out.println(p.getName());
}
```

Is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is what the JPA 2.0 specification says about IN expressions:

> #### 4.6.9 In Expressions
>
> The syntax for the use of the
>   comparison operator [NOT] IN in a
>   conditional expression is as follows:
>
> ```
> in_expression ::=
>     {state_field_path_expression | type_discriminator} [NOT] IN
>         { ( in_item {, in_item}* ) | (subquery) | collection_valued_input_parameter }
> in_item ::= literal | single_valued_input_parameter
> ```
>
> ...

So according to the specification, the correct syntax when passing a *collection_valued_input_parameter* is without parenthesis:

```
select p from Person p where p.name in ?1
```

And this works with EclipseLink.

Comment: Hi. I did what you said but it did not work to me. I´m using EclipseLink 2.5.1.

Answer (score 0):

Using EclipseLink, you need to use a name to your paramether.

Ex.:

```
TypedQuery<Person> q = em.createQuery("select p from Person p where p.name in :names", Person.class);
List<String> names = Arrays.asList(new String[] { "Bill Gates", "Steve Jobs" });
q.setParameter("names", names);
```

The symbol "?" does not work using clause "in". It was tested in EclipseLink 2.5.1.