# QueryDSL Unexpected Token , with any() and in clause

Tags: java, hibernate, querydsl

I have two models, `Location` and `LocationAttribute`, with a Many to Many relationship.
I have a list of LocationAttribute IDs, and would like to find all Locations that have at least one 
of those attributes.

Location.java:

```
@Entity
public class Location {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="LOCATION_ID")
    protected int id;

    @ManyToMany(targetEntity = LocationAttribute.class)
    @JoinTable(name="LOCATION_TO_LOCATION_ATTRIBUTE",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="LOCATION_ID", referencedColumnName = "LOCATION_ID"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="LOCATION_ATTRIBUTE_ID", referencedColumnName = "LOCATION_ATTRIBUTE_ID")
    )
    private List<LocationAttribute> locationAttributes;
}
```

LocationAttribute.java:

```
@Entity
public class LocationAttribute {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="LOCATION_ATTRIBUTE_ID")
    protected int id;
}
```

I tried the following QueryDSL code:

```
List<Integer> locationAttributeIds = new ArrayList<Integer>();
locationAttributeIds.add(1);
locationAttributeIds.add(2);
locationAttributeIds.add(3);

QLocation location = QLocation.location;
JPAQuery query = new JPAQuery(entityManager, JPQLTemplates.DEFAULT);
query.from(location) .where(location.locationAttributes.any().id.in(locationAttributeIds));
query.list(location);
```

The code works fine if locationAttributeIds has 0 or 1 elements. However, when I have more than 1 element, I get this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: , near line 5, column 53 [select location
from ch.locatee.test.querydslerror.locatee.Location location
where exists (select location_locationAttributes_cc6d8
from location.locationAttributes as location_locationAttributes_cc6d8
where location_locationAttributes_cc6d8.id in :x1_0_, :x1_1_, :x1_2_)]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1750)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:458)
    at com.mysema.query.jpa.impl.AbstractJPAQuery.getResultList(AbstractJPAQuery.java:194)
    at com.mysema.query.jpa.impl.AbstractJPAQuery.list(AbstractJPAQuery.java:246)
    at ch.locatee.test.querydslerror.locatee.AppTest.testSomething(AppTest.java:63)
```

I found quite a few related sites to my question but am not sure how I would fix the problem.

- https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/issues/72
- [How to set collection items for in-clause in jpql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3879589/how-to-set-collection-items-for-in-clause-in-jpql)
- https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-6913
- https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/issues/271

I made a quick test project, you can find it on Github: https://github.com/bekoeppel/QueryDslInErrorTest. `mvn test` produces the above error.

I would appreciate your ideas how I can find all `Locations` that have at least one of the `LocationAttribute.id`s from the list. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following JPAQuery constructor instead

```
new JPAQuery(entityManager);
```

`JPQLTemplates` provides generic serialization, that doesn't find all of Hibernate's JPQL variations. With only the EntityManager argument Querydsl will pick the right JPQLTemplates subclass instance for you.